# How do I compute distance between points using pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im using python 3 and I would like to use the distance formula to graph the difference in the x,y,z components relative to my file named JCFI. The other file im comparing it to is called CALV. I imported them both as dataframes using pandas then split them so they are the same length and the dates in each file match.

Here is what I am trying.

```
#matching dates between JCFI and CALV
date = JCFIdf.iloc[:1694,:1]
xcomp = JCFIdf.iloc[:1694,1:2]
ycomp = JCFIdf.iloc[:1694,2:3]
zcomp = JCFIdf.iloc[:1694,3:4] 
xcomp2 = CALVdf.iloc[201:1520,1:2]
ycomp2 = CALVdf.iloc[201:1520,2:3]
zcomp2 = CALVdf.iloc[201:1520,3:4]
diffx = (xcomp2 - xcomp)
diffy = (ycomp2 - ycomp)
diffz = (zcomp2 - zcomp)

#compute distance
distance = sqrt((diffx)**2 + (diffy)**2 + (diffz)**2) 
print(distance)
```

The error I get is 
    "TypeError: must be real number, not DataFrame"

So I am wondering do I have to somehow extract all the values out of the dataframes in order to put into distance formula or is there a function in pandas so that i can  make this work?

Comment: use `np.sqrt` instead of `math.sqrt`

Comment: ``sqrt`` cannot be applied on non-scalar values (here ``diffx`` and its variants are matrices (``DataFrame``)). Also, you should provide an example of the data (and I said an example, not the whole file!!) for this kind of questions (even if, in the present case, this is not required).

Comment: `iloc` return a DataFrame or a Serie and you are trying to make math operation on it. It won't work. You should get the exact value you want from the DataFrame returned by `iloc` before doing math operations. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extracting-rows-using-pandas-iloc/

Comment: @Maxouille Nope, you **can** make math operations in data frames. Just have to use the appropriate libraries for that.

Comment: Yes, my comment was not very clear sorry. I meant that it's impossible to compute `sqrt`  with a DataFrame. But it has been explained in other comments.

Comment: Again, you *can*. Using `np.sqrt`, for example. No need to work the individual `int` or `float` items. Take a look at [vectorization](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html)

Comment: when i used np.sqrt, it worked but gave me a dataframe with [1694 rows x 3 columns] filled with 'NaN' and no actual value

Comment: @Kdkempa Then you have to understand why by looking into the data. Post a your data frame `.head()` for us to take a look at the data.

Comment: @RafaelC sorry im new to this site and coding so i just linked a screenshot of part of the JCFI - file https://imgur.com/LcufJxp. There are many columns but I just care about the first 4

Answer (score 0):

here is a vectorized solution using numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dist = np.sqrt((df.xcomp - df.xcomp2) ** 2 +
               (df.ycomp - df.ycomp2) ** 2 +
               (df.zcomp - df.zcomp2) ** 2)

#if you want to put the result in df
df['dist'] = pd.Series(dist)
```